# Transform elements of list in elements of a data frame

Tags: r

I have these data:

```
a <- data.frame(element1 = c("JB", "AC", "DO", "MR"),
                element2 = c(1, 3, 4, 2))
```

```
b <- list(JB = c("a", "b", "s"), DO = c("ER", "TR", "OP"))
```

I want to create a new data frame `ab` similar to data frame `a`, but such that the elements of the first column are the elements of the list b. I.e. in the new `ab` data frame, the elements of the first column that have the same title as the elements of the list b take the value of the elements in the list `b`.

**EDIT**: The output should be the same as a, but with element1 elements being lists:

```
> ab
  element1 element2
1       JB        1
2       AC        3
3       DO        4
4       MR        2
```

Comment: Your desired output is same as `a`. Can you explain that?

Comment: @inter Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may check out this tutorial: https://statisticsglobe.com/convert-list-of-vectors-to-data-frame-in-r It shows 2 examples on how to convert a list to a data frame in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that just

```
ab <- within(a, element1 <- b[element1])
```

Output

```
> str(ab)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ element1:List of 4
  ..$ JB: chr  "a" "b" "s"
  ..$ NA: NULL
  ..$ DO: chr  "ER" "TR" "OP"
  ..$ NA: NULL
 $ element2: num  1 3 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- data.frame(element1 = c("JB", "AC", "DO", "MR"),
            element2 = c(1, 3, 4, 2))

b <- data.frame(JB = c("a", "b", "s"), DO = c("ER", "TR", "OP"))

merge(b,a)
```

This should do the job.
Output will be:

```
   JB DO element1 element2
1   a ER       JB        1
2   b TR       JB        1
3   s OP       JB        1
4   a ER       AC        3
5   b TR       AC        3
6   s OP       AC        3
7   a ER       DO        4
8   b TR       DO        4
9   s OP       DO        4
10  a ER       MR        2
11  b TR       MR        2
12  s OP       MR        2
```

Comment: I wrote a comment regarding the desired output. do you think it is doable?

Comment: Do you want column 1 of b in column 1 of ab? I am a bit confused as in your edit the output is same as input a

Comment: Yes, the ouput should be the sort of the same, only that the elements should be different: not string but elements of the list. Not sure if that is feasible since I am new to R. Sort of, when I click ab[1, 1], I get a list and not a string as in a.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but you can try `merge(b[,1],a[,1])`. Here a[,1] represents all rows and column 1 of a and b[,1] represents all rows with column 1 of b. if you want some other output then you can change row or column number.